# threejs - Defect in rotation - THREE.OrbitControls

Tags: three.js

I use OrbitControls now but still i have strange bug. It is hard to explain. When i drag mouse down in the begin work normally and then in one moment whole scene begin to rotate in wrong direction and flip my whole scene.

I got warnings :

> OrbitControls.js:1103 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to
>   a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as
>   'passive' to make the page more responsive. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Here is my code:

```
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)

    controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.05;
    controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
    controls.minDistance = 14;
    controls.maxDistance = 120;

    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 3;

    controls.target.set(5, 4, -20);
```

- I need to limit rotation , disable 360 rotating scene. 
  For example i wanna allow max angle of 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.maxAzimuthAngle)? It outlines four different properties to limit angles of rotation. These are the defaults:

```js
// How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
// Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
controls.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

// How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
// If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
controls.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
controls.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians
```

#### Edit:

The above solution is for `OrbitControls`, which is not what the original question asked. `TrackballControls` does not offer the ability to limit angles of rotation.

Comment: I take last version but still no rotate preventing. Threejs is also last version.

Comment: There is no "minPolarAngle" property in this lib you miss with Orbit lib....

Comment: @NikolaLukic My mistake, you are correct. For some reason I thought you were asking about `OrbitControls`, but you were actually asking for `TrackballControls`. Trackball does not have those min/max properties. They're both very similar, except Trackball does not keep a constant "up" orientation.

Comment: I predefined question ! Mr. @Marquizzo if you have some suggestion ...

Comment: i setup camera.up.z = 0 and i fix rotation in right way !

Answer (score 2):

Try this, i had a familiar issue and applied it to my code and worked
`camera.up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );`